# Error when closing a form with C++

Tags: forms, c++-cli

I'm having trouble with closing a C++ form (it's been years since I've used it). I've created the form (form_options.h), and it displays just fine with no code in any of the controls.

However, my first bit of manual coding (to close the form when 'Cancel' is clicked throws an error when I compile the project -

> error C2039: 'close' : is not a member of 'MusicRenaming::form_options'

Here is the code in question -

```
 private: System::Void btnCancel_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
     this->close();
 }
```

I seem to remember that this was all I had to do to close forms, but the error seems to be indicating that I need to actually write a close function? If this is the case, can I get some help with how to close the form? Thanks.

Comment: The method is [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, forgot C++ was case sensitive to that level!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`close` should be `Close` with an uppercase 'C'.